# configure authentication on a send only postfix relay server

Tags: active-directory, postfix-mta

My environment has 3 server.

```
Application server ---> Postfix ---> Mailserver
```

Application server that relays to the postfix server, and the postfix servers relay to the mail server. It's a send-only postfix.

I am able to send the email now, however, I would like to have an authentication between application server to postfix server.
Currently my postfix server is listening on port 25, and anyone within the `mynetworks` is able to use it to relay email.

I have set the following:

/etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
```

main.cf

```
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
```

I am able to telnet port 25, and successfully use auth login with the base64 , however, I am still able to send email without authentication.

My end goal is to set up the authentication(against AD) when relaying the postfix server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post your main.cf and master.cf as whole (occulting sensitive informations), it would be nice.

> I am able to telnet port 25, and successfully use auth login with the base64 , however, I am still able to send email without authentication.

It is more common sense to use dedicated ports: 465 or 587 if you want authentication and leave port 25 for non-authenticated connections.

Still cannot tell why you server is not relaying if your full configuration is not available to us

Comment: I have switch to use dovecot to authenticate. thank you for your reply.